# NHibernate part load entity from database, part load from WCF

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, orm, lazy-loading, iusertype

I've been looking at loading enities from WCF:

[NHibernate: Lazy loading of IUserType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286132/nhibernate-lazy-loading-of-iusertype)

[NHibernate: Many-to-one IUserType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302186/nhibernate-many-to-one-iusertype)

[Preloading IUserType with values from webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322874/preloading-iusertype-with-values-from-webservice)

I've worked out how to lazy load the entity from WCF: you have to create your own proxy which calls WCF and return it from IUserType, but I'll blog this at some point.

My question now is, can I part load an entity from the database in the usual way, so some properties are populated (ones that are stored locally) but for other properties, it has to call WCF? The local properties are ones that might be searched on, or returned in a query (Can't call WCF for each one - would be too slow), and the others would be called if the system needed to perform some business logic on it.

The problem is that I don't think I can use IUserType here, because I would need to use bag/set for my collections as I would want them to be eager loaded. Is there any way this can be done?

**Edit:**

It would be ideal if I could force NHibernate to return a proxy, and some how I could have access to the interceptor on that proxy, or even specify my own interceptor?

Comment: Isn't this just creating the properties as you would normally .... and not map them?

Comment: Some of the properties would be mapped to the database as normal, and then there will be some others that, when accessed, would need to be read from WCF (or whatever). Hopefully one call would access all the extra properties.

Comment: I still don't see the problem. Isn't it as simple as just creating the property you need and do your own lazy loading inside it (which could call a web service or whatever)?

Comment: Do you mean in the actual entity itself? This would cause the domain to have external dependencies on the WCF services. I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is possible to inject your own custom interceptor. You need to provide an interceptor for the session which instantiates the objects and sets your own LazyInitializer, see [here](http://kozmic.pl/2011/03/20/working-with-nhibernate-without-default-constructors/) under **Proxy fac­tory**

Comment: That link is very helpful. I overrided the ProxyFactory's Getproxy() method, adding another interceptor to it. This interceptor checks the property/method accessed on the entity, and if one of the external fields is accessed, the rest of the property is loaded from WCF.